# Read line by line from standard input Bash

Tags: bash, unix, stdin

I'm studying [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) language and an exam track says this:

> It should read one input (from standard input) at a time (each entry
>   is a string and then ends with a newline).

My questions are two:

1. How do I read line by line from standard input in Bash? Until now I used `"read string"` but I do not think that it reads a line at a time.
2. I do not know if this is a stupid question , but once created the script how can I give more lines to the script  as input (read from standard input of course). For example from [stdin](/questions/tagged/stdin) I insert two lines (`hello` and `world`). How do I give to the bash script these two lines?

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> 1. How do I read line by line from standard input in Bash? Until now I
>    used "read string" but I do not think that it reads a line at a time.

The prototype for `read` is:

```
read [options] name[s ...]
```

`read` will read a `line` of input into `name name1 name2 ...` splitting the line based on the contents of the **Internal Field Separator** (`IFS`). The default for `IFS` is `' \t\n'` (that is `space` `tab` `newline`). If you only provide a single variable to `read`, you will read the entire line into that variable (unless you have set a new delimiter with the `-d` option to `read`). If you provide more than one variable, (e.g. `read -r name name1`) word splitting will occur based on the current value of `IFS`. Meaning if you provide the string `hello world` to:

```
read -r name
```

`name="hello world"`. On the other hand, if you provide the same string to:

```
read -r name name1
```

`name="hello"`, `name1="world"`. What if you have excess words in the line but only 2 variables? Say your string is now `"hello big wide world"`, what happens with:

```
read -r name name1
```

`name="hello"`, `name1="big wide world"`. The words in `string` are assigned to your variables in order and if there are insufficient variables to hold each word in the string, the last variable will contain all remaining words in the string not previously assigned.

You change how word splitting occurs by altering `IFS`. Take a close look at the answer provided by anubhava for an example. You are free to specify any character you would like the words to be split on. (helpful in say parsing a `csv` file to set `IFS=$',\n'` and have the words split on `','` instead of space)

To ensure you read an entire line into a variable, you can provide only a single variable to `read` and set `IFS='$\n'` to ensure word splitting only occurs on `newline`. (**Note:** providing the change as part of the `while` loop limits the `IFS` alteration to the scope of that loop. For example:

```
while IFS=$'\n' read -r line; do
    # do whatever with line
done
```

Will ensure that each line on `stdin` will be read into `line` while preserving normal word-splitting outside the loop. Inside the loop you can then add each line to an array as anubhava shows in his answer. (to preserve all whitespace `IFS=` is used)

Answer (score 11):

You can do something like this:

```
# array to hold all lines read
lines=()

# read all lines in lines array
while IFS= read -r line; do
    lines+=( "$line" )
done < file

# read 3 more lines from stdin
for ((i=0; i<3; i++)); do
   read -rp "Enter a line: " line
   lines+=( "$line" )
done
```

Comment: what about [`mapfile`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-mapfile)?

Comment: Yes sure `mapfile` or `readarray` can both be used if on BASH ver > 4

Comment: What does the IFS= part do? Is it simply setting IFS to ~empty~ , or, it's putting the output of 'read' into IFS?  thanks.

Comment: It sets `IFS` to empty string

Comment: @anubhava how would you `readarray` stdin from inside a script? I guess inside the script `readarray "$1"` and `./script.sh < <(echo "a"; echo "b";)`

Comment: Without < and any thing after that will make it read from stdin